# Angular JS async two API requests

Tags: angularjs

In Angular at the moment I have this:

```
app.factory("myService", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        doBoth: function(data) {
            return $q.all([$http.post("/search/local", data), $http.post("/search/shape", data)]);
        }
    };
});
```

and i call it like this:

```
$scope.$on("localSearch", function(event, data) {
    return myService.doBoth(data);
});
```

However I do not think it is happening asynchronously. They both take quite a time to get fulfilled so I need Angular to request both at the same time, so the complete request isn't one + the other - but the quickest time they both get returned in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fire callback after both queries completed, place it in `$q.then()` method.

```
$scope.$on("localSearch", function(event, data) {
  return myService
    .doBoth(data)
    .then(function (response) {
      // both deffered completed
    });
});
```

I've created sample here http://plnkr.co/edit/7G8oFMSx8cPC98zDhlNq?p=preview

Comment: Will this send both queries at the same time? Or one after the other

Comment: Yep, it's seen from $q source code and for more visual proof see http://d.pr/i/WKHY . Actually it works in your example also - because it's the way $q executes futures, you're only missing callback part

Comment: Okay, I know I am now being difficult, but is there a way to grab one and then the other done. Its waiting for them both to be done.. however It would be neat if when it was done it was available

Comment: Then you need to refactor your service to not use `$q.all()` but rather create multiple defers. See updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FycwSI